# Regex only for specific domain name in URL

Tags: php, regex

As much as I've tried I can't seem to find the correct regex to locate what I'm after here.

I only want to select the first instance of the url that matches the domain **www.myweb.com** from the following...

```
Some text https://www.myweb.com/page/cat/323123442321-rghe432 and then another https://www.adifferentsite.com/fsdhjss/erwr
```

I need to completely ignore the second url **www.adifferentsite.com** and only work with the first one that matches **www.myweb.com**, ignoring any other possible instances of **www.myweb.com**

Once the first matching domain is discovered I need to store the rest of the url that comes after it...

```
page/cat/323123442321-rghe432
```

...into a new variable $newvar, so...

```
$newvar = 'page/cat/323123442321-rghe432';
```

I'm trying :

```
return preg_replace_callback( '/http://www.myweb.com/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]+/', array( __CLASS__, 'my_callback' ), $newvar );
```

I've read tons of documents on how to detect url's but can't find anything about detecting a specific url.

I really can't grasp how to formulate regex so this formula is incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** Edited the question to be a bit more specific and hopefully a bit easier to resolve.

Comment: If you need to match, why replace? And when you created a regex, did you pay attention at the regex delimiters? I guess you get an Uknown delimiters error.

Comment: I'm replacing because I'm going to be formulating the link into an oEmbed link where the url format is different. so https://www.myweb.com/page/cat/323123442321-rghe432 will become https://embed.myweb.com/page/cat/323123442321-rghe432 when rendered after this filter

Comment: Regex wise, I just don't understand how it works. I've read and read and read and just can't seem to grasp the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Ok, I think you can just use [`'~\bhttps?://www\.myweb\.com/(\S+)~'`](https://regex101.com/r/tZ7qV9/1) regex and push the `$m[1]` into the array for "the rest of URL".

Comment: When you say push the $m[1] into the array for the rest of the url, could you explain that a bit more please? I understand what you are saying but I don't know how I would do that?

Comment: Your example shows you want to capture the `-` but you didn't include that in your character class. Do `[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+` And what @stribizhev is referring to is the `/` you use to wrap your regex. You need to use a different character since you're telling the regex to look for that in your regex (`http://`) you can change the wrapping `/` to `~` or `@`. [The php docs talk about it](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Comment: Here is a [demo](https://ideone.com/0eLlrn) of what I mean.

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev that should be enough to get me going in the right direction

Comment: @stribizhev I'm trying to alter your code so it doesn't store the results as an array. I only need to return the first matching instance so I don't need to use an array here. I'm not managing to make it work without using an array though. Is using an array the only way to do this?

Comment: @Grant: I posted an improved demo in my answer with some explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `preg_replace_callback` and pass an array into the anonymous function (or just your custom callback function) to fill it with all the necessary URL parts.

Here is a [demo](https://ideone.com/0eLlrn):

```
$rests = array();
$re = '~\b(https?://)www\.myweb\.com/(\S+)~'; 
$str = "Some text https://www.myweb.com/page/cat/323123442321-rghe432 and then another https://www.adifferentsite.com/fsdhjss/erwr"; 
echo $result = preg_replace_callback($re, function ($m) use (&$rests) {
    array_push($rests, $m[2]);
    return $m[1] . "embed.myweb.com/" . $m[2];
}, $str) . PHP_EOL;
print_r($rests);
```

Results:

```
Some text https://embed.myweb.com/page/cat/323123442321-rghe432 and then another https://www.adifferentsite.com/fsdhjss/erwr
Array
(
    [0] => page/cat/323123442321-rghe432
)
```

A couple of words:

- `'~\b(https?://)www\.myweb\.com/(\S+)~'` has `~` as a **[regex delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)**, so you do not have to escape `/`
- It is declared with a single-quoted literal, so you do not have to use double-escaping for `\\S`
- It matches and captures into **[capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)** 2 substrings: `\b(https?://)` (that matches a whole word `http` or `https` followed by `://`) and `(\S+)` (that matches 1 or more non-whitespace characters). These capturing groups are marked with `(...)` in the pattern and can be accessed via `$matches[n]` where *n* is the id of the capturing group.

**UPDATE**

If you only need to replace the ***first occurrence of the URL***, pass the *limit* argument to the [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$rest = "";
$re = '~\b(https?://)www\.myweb\.com/(\S+\b)~'; 
$str = "Some text https://www.myweb.com/page/cat/323123442321-rghe432, another http://www.myweb.com/page/cat/323123442321-rghe432 and then another https://www.adifferentsite.com/fsdhjss/erwr"; 
echo $result = preg_replace_callback($re, function ($m) use (&$rest) {
    $rest = $m[2];
    return $m[1] . "embed.myweb.com/" . $m[2];
}, $str, 1) . PHP_EOL;
//-LIMIT ^ - HERE -
echo $rest;
```

See [another IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/h3OzUY)

Comment: This works perfectly, but I don't need an array in this instance. I only need to match and collect the url for the first instance of the url. Is this routine possible without using an array?

Comment: Just note that `use (&$rests)` requires the use of `&$` since we need to write to the array inside the callback function.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have `Some text https://www.myweb.com/page1 and https://www.myweb.com/page2` and you only want to get the first one replaced only? Use `1` as the last argument to `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Thank you @stribizhev that is perfect!

Comment: One last question if you don't mind. What if I wanted to only collect PART of the of the url. So from https://www.myweb.com/page/cat/323123442321-rghe432 - I only wanted to store 'page/cat' (without trailing slash after cat) to the $rest var. Just trying to understand how to use regex a bit better.

Comment: Use negated character class `[^/]*` to match 0 or more characters other than `/` to stay inside the URL parts. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU5yS9/1).

Comment: Oh man I wish I knew more about regex.. I just can't get it working.. Demo - https://ideone.com/sPRcOW

Comment: Why using `preg_replace`? You say you need to get the value. Use `preg_match`: `$re = '~https?://www\.myweb\.com/([^/]*/[^/]*)~';
$str = "Some text https://www.myweb.com/page/cat/323123442321-rghe432, another http://www.myweb.com/page/cat/323123442321-rghe432 and then another https://www.adifferentsite.com/fsdhjss/erwr"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $m);
echo $m[1];` ([demo](http://ideone.com/kWXSKl))

Comment: But I need to remove the original text url completely and replace it with a new url that I will generate using the matched elements

Comment: Ok, use [this one](https://ideone.com/PyQK0q). `$re = '~(https?://)www\.myweb\.com/(([^/]*/[^/]*)\S+\b)~';` and then `$result = preg_replace_callback($re, function ($m) use (&$rest) {
 $rest = $m[3];
 return $m[1] . "embed.myweb.com/" . $m[2];
}, $str, 1)`

Comment: That is exactly what I was after. Thank you so much, I've learned a lot more about regex in this thread than I've been able to do reading anything else.